# Modulepath and Classpath can't be found in Java Build Path Libraries

Tags: java, eclipse, ide, buildpath, module-path

Beginner of Java and not knowledgeable that much in Eclipse IDE. So the problem is that my project "xdriscollDialogBoxTest" doesn't have the Modulepath and Classpath under my Java Build Path Libraries. Additionally, a new class was created under src named "(default package)" after configuring with the AddLibrary.

[modulepath and classpath not found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U2e5w.png)

What I want to happen right now is to restore everything as is (bringing back my Modulepath, Classpath, removing "JRE System Library [CDC-1.0/Foundation-1.9 (jdk-17)]" and removing the "(default package)" that has a red mark error.

I added a library which is "CDC-1.0/Foundation-1.9 (jdk-17)" and I got the idea from a YouTube video that shows me how fix package javax.swing is not accessible. I expected a GUI to pop out, but got an error(https://i.stack.imgur.com/PSWEb.png). Hence, why I want to restore everything back before adding the "CDC-1.0/Foundation-1.9 (jdk-17)" incident. Don't want to redo or remake another project though, because all of my school activities/groupworks are there.

Comment: The _Libraries_ tab shows two system libraries. Only the first is used to determine the Java version used in your project and the first one is before Java 9. And before Java 9 means no modulepath, only a classpath. Does selecting `JRE System Library [CDC-1.0/Foundation-1.0]` and hitting the _Remove_ button fix your issue?

Comment: Hi! I deleted the CDC-1.0... leaving JRE System Library [JavaSE-17] untouched. Still, the modulepath and classpath is no where to be seen and the (default package) is still there under src . Is there a way to redo what I've done? Forgive me, but the terms aren't getting into my head that much. If there's a way or step-by-step process to bring back modulepath and classpath, I would very much appreciate the guidance.

Comment: Please go to _Project > Properties: Java Compiler_ and hit _Apply and Close_. If this does not help, show what you have there (_Compiler compliance level_ should be set to 17 in your case).

Comment: The run configuration may have copied the invalid JRE settings. When you delete it before running again, Eclipse will create a new one with the fixed settings. The problem with your “default package” might be entirely unrelated; why don’t you open the folder to see what’s inside?